# Recommended Eclipse-friendly checkstyle configuration for java open source projects?

Tags: java, eclipse, checkstyle

I'd like to open source some code of mine.  To make it easier for contributors, I'd like to set up a checkstyle configuration to go along with it.  However, my recent experience is that the Eclipse Checkstyle plugin's ability to generate formatter rules that correspond to a checkstyle.xml file leaves something to be desired; that is, I need to manually tweak the generated formatter rules quite a bit to get them to actually format a file such that it complies with the checkstyle rules.

Are there "reference" checkstyle.xml files out there somewhere that are considered semi-standard for open source projects, and which are Eclipse-friendly in the sense that that formatter rules generated from them by the Checkstyle plugin are compatible?

Answer (score 3):

I would definitely recommend [Geosoft](http://geosoft.no/development/javastyle.html) Checkstyle Configuration.
The same is available [here](http://geosoft.no/development/geosoft_checks.xml).

Answer (score 2):

The default Eclipse checkstyle rules, are the Sun standard rules, which is a minimum set of rules.
You could use these.